# XMLHolder in groovy unable to Retrieve value

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have the following xml:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <Login_v1Response>
         <result xsi:nil="true"/>
         <opSessionID>FjqkjEjipbhkdiin</opSessionID>
      </Login_v1Response>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have the following code in groovy which returns me null:

```
def groovyUtils=new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("Step1-Login#response")
log.info holder.getNodeValue("//SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/Login_v1Response/opSessionID")
```

Please help out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using namespaces in your script, without defining what those namespaces are. For just reading values it is generally easier to use wildcards and not worry about them.

```
def groovyUtils=new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("Step1-Login#Response")
log.info holder.getNodeValue("//*:opSessionID")
```

Or even something simpler like:

```
log.info context.expand('${Step1-Login#Response#//*:opSessionID}')
```